# Mosaic Worldview images

Tags: qgis, envi, mosaic

I have 4 tiles of worldview images. in some part of each image they overlap each other. I would like to have a single output having them all together. As far as I know I should Mosaic them, right?
I have tried to mosaic them in Envi 5 and Qgis. Its strange what I get as an output.

ENVI--> Even though I have selected all the bands but still I get single grayscale band as an output.
[image]

QGIS--> I tried to mosaic the tiles but the output is also weird.
[image]

Comment: What exactly did you try in QGIS? Did http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/raster_mosaicing_and_clipping.html not work?

Comment: I tried to Raster-->Miscellaneous-->Merge in Qgis, but the results are strange as shown...